# Set Input Parameter in Custom Workflow Activity, Dynamic values are not populating?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

On the saving of Case record I want to assign the case to respective Agent based on case type , sub type and Client/Account,
I have a Assignee field on Account form which I need to get the Agent's name to Assign the case.

I am creating a custom workflow activity for that, but while writing it I stuck how to fetch Case forms record on which I apply logic.
Please suggest what is the good approach, do I need to make a retrieve call to fetch these parameters or something else.

While setting the Custom Step Input Properties drop down fields are not populating to select the Dynamics Values.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use plugin, as the documented/supported preimage is available in plugin steps + flexible.

You have to look for type, subtype, etc in target entity (incident in your case) or preimage if needed to apply logic.

If you still want to use workflow, go ahead & follow this [article](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2014/10/13/using-preentityimage-and-postentityimage-in-workflows).

> we can always read Pre image and Post image in the plug-in for various purpose. However, in workflow, we may sometimes want to read Pre Image for some purpose. Now we can also read Pre Images and Post Images in the workflow using Execution Context. It uses the same Plug-in Architecture and hence we can use it to read Pre Images and Post Images. However, this concept is not documented in the SDK so it might be unsupported.